# How do you load two apps onto the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Eclipse to develop a couple of apps for Android phones.  I want to experiment with one app starting the other via startActivity().  What is unclear to me, is how to I get both apps loaded onto the emulator.  How do I get both apps onto the emulator so, I can test their ability to start each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First start one from Eclipse (it will be installed). Then start the next. Now both are in your emulator.

Comment: Yes, provided that eclipse re-uses the same emulator instance for the second app instead of creating a new one, or that your emulator is set up with a persistent data partition, then the first app should still be installed when eclipse deploys the second.   You can also use the adb install command to load an apk onto the emulator.